# Temporary failure in name resolution after computer restart

Tags: server, ethernet

i know that this was aked a million times but i tested everything and nothing worker

**how it happend**

I was messing around on my mother board trying to fit a heat sync(with my computer on) and then it just restarted itself without me pressing anything when the computer was on I got `a start job is running  for wait for network to be configured`(i fixed that) and when the computer was on and i tried using the internet i got `temporary failure in name resolution`

I have an ethernet connection if that matters

Answer (score -1):

i just ended up reinstalling ubuntu